# Plugin Post Operation Lock record in Database

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I am calling a web service from my plugin whih query the CRM databae and return some data to the plugin. When I register my plugin in Post-Operation Update I am getting a time out exception which is caused by the web service trying to query the databse. When I register my plugin in Pre-Operation Update it is working like a charm.

My Question is: DOES CRM DATABASE LOCK A RECORD ON POST OPERATION UPDATE ONLY AND NOT ON PRE OPERATION UPDATE?

Comment: this plugin is sync or async?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There really shouldn't be a reason to query the web service for information about the same record you are updating. You should be able to use `PreImages` and/or `PostImages` to make that data available in your plugins. That way you don't need to query the web service during the update.

Comment: Using Images to get values from the Target entity is a best practice instead of querying.  
BUT: If he's both querying and updating the Target record within the transaction, it should never be locked against itself.  Any queries or updates within the same transaction will be free to do anything to the locked records.  The lock only applies to other operations that happen during timeframe of the lock, but are happening outside of the same plugin transaction.

Comment: Good point - I have edited my answer to remove the erroneous paragraph about locks.